# Angular2 trigger CanActivate while page is active

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

As far as I understand it the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface in Angular2 is only effective on route changes. So if I have a page *p* that requires the user to be logged in I can create a guard that implements the CanActivate interface which will allow the [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) to activate *p* only if the user is logged in.

But what happens when *p* is active and the user gets logged out? I have tried to find best practices on checking if a page is allowed to be active without changing the route in the RouterModule but I can't find anything useful. Lets say page *p* is active and requires a login. Now a logout is triggered somehow while p is active but no route change is involved. Lets say the server responded with a 401 and the app notices the user is not logged in anymore. What would be the best practice to check if the active page requires a login and take measures accordingly? It could be that the active page does not require a login. In that case everything should remain as it is.

Comment: I was having this same issue just today. I found a solution that better-fit my needs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680250/angular2-how-to-reload-page-with-router-recheck-canactivate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may add `data` with your routes, which you may use later to check if authentication is required for that route or not,

something like below,

```
{
  path: ..., 
  component: ..., 
  canActivate: [CanActivateGuard], 
  data: { authRequired: true }
}
```

in the logout trigger, you can inject `ActivatedRoute` to check on the activated routes data to determine if you want to send the user to login page or not,

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {}
...
someCallBack(){
  if(!!this.route.snapshot.data 
     && this.route.snapshot.data.authRequired == true){

     // redirect to login page

  }
}
```